# Scheme - Correct use of "and" in an if-sentence

Tags: if-statement, scheme, conditional-statements, racket

I'm currently writing a small project in Scheme for an assignment. I have not been using Scheme for long, so I am not strong on the syntax.

The problem is using "and" in an if-sentence. I have a list of appointments in a calendar, but I only want those that are between a certain time interval. Hence, i need to check on start and end time.

What I would like to achieve would look something like this in C#:

```
List<appointment> appointments = new List<appointment>();

    foreach (appointment app in calendar) {
        if(app.getstart() >= from-time && app.getend() <= to-time) {
            appoinments.add(app);
        }
    }
```

What I currently have in Scheme is this:

```
(define (time-calendar cal from-time to-time)
  (map (lambda (app)(if (> from-time (send 'getstart app)) #t #f))
         (send 'getappointments cal)))
```

Takes a calendar "cal", and a time interval (from-time and to-time)
I then get appointments (app) from cal and iterate over them. For each of them I check if from-time is greater than the starttime of "app". Returns true or false accordingly. This works great, but I still need to consider if the appointment also ends before "to-time". This should be a simple matter of adding another condition, but I simply can not get it to work.

Can anyone help me with the correct syntax for checking on a second variable?
I know about [Racket documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html), but I still can not fix my problem.

I tried changing out the if sentence for cond.

I also tried a bunch of variations of the "and" part, similar to this, but can not get the syntax right:

```
(define (time-calendar cal from-time to-time)
  (map (lambda (app)(if (and((> from-time (send 'getstart app))) (< to-time (send 'getend app))) #t #f))
         (send 'getappointments cal)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```scm
(and expression1 expression2 ...)
```

Excessive parentheses are understood as if your expressions are to be applied like a procedure. eg.

```
(and ((if some-var + -) 4 6))
```

The result here is either -2 or 10 depending on the value of some-var. The `and` is redundant as `(and x)` is the same as `x`.

As for your code, here is how it should be:

```
(define (time-calendar cal from-time to-time)
  (map (lambda (app)
         (and (> from-time (send 'getstart app)) 
              (< to-time (send 'getend app))))
       (send 'getappointments cal)))
```

The `if` was redundant since `and` evaluates to `#f` if one of them are false. `>` and `<` always evaluate to either `#f` or `#t`. Even if it didn't you could use all data except `#f` as true so in most cases extra `if` is redundant. If you needed something else that what the expressions returned you use if and the whole and expressions is the predicate.
Now since `>` takes many arguments you actually don't need `and`:

```
(define (time-calendar cal from-time to-time)
  (map (lambda (app)
         (> from-time (send 'getstart app) to-time))
       (send 'getappointments cal)))
```

Comment: I would never have considered that I could skip the "if" entirely. Thank you for the elaborate explanation, I understand your answer perfectly!

Comment: My next readup might have to be on evaluation of true and false - No matter how I choose from-time, to-time and the time stored in appointments, everything evaluates to false. Well, at least I got a bit further. :)

Comment: @Treelink I didn't proof read you logic. It seems you may need to switch `>` with `<`. `(> from-time (send 'getstart app) to-time)` means `(send 'getstart app)` needs to be smaller than from-time and larger than to-time. eg `(> 5 3 1) ; ==> #t` since `5 > 3 > 1`. you see?

Comment: You were partly right again! I messed up somewhere else as well, but > should indeed have been < as well! Thanks once again! You have really been helpful to say the least.